# Why does Multiple media field returns same image?

Tags: graphql, gatsby, strapi

I am working on a sample blog web app using Gatsby and Strapi. To test the multiple-media capability:

- I created a test dataset, where the Collection Type definition was a single "Name" field and a field for multiple media.

  **name**: Text, **images**: List[Media]
- Then, I created few entries, expecting to use the following graphql query to retrive the data from strapi: [query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7gAP.png)

However, the publicURL property for each returned row is the same image url - the first uploaded image. As a result, the web app displays the same image for all three records.

Based on posts online, I suspected it might be a cache issue and tried `gatsby clean` multiple times and `gatsby develop`. However, the images are still getting mixed up.

I'm stuck on identifying why this might be happening. Does anyone have any thoughts on what could be the problem? I'd appreciate the insight.

Comment: I am pretty sure that `lists` is an array

Answer (score 0):

Do not pull `formats` just get full `lists` as an object.

Modify your GraphQL query then handle `lists` inside gatsby.

```
console.log(typeof(lists))
```